# Strange null pointer with jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-batch

A strange NullPointer while using jdbcTemplate keeps bugging me and I can't find the origin of the NullPointerException.

Source Snippet:

```
@Slf4j
public class ApproximationBuilder {

  // [...]

  public static DistributionApproximation buildQuadraticApproximation(JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate, String table, String column) {
    int id_min = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT MIN(" + column + ") from " + table + " WHERE " + column + " IS NOT NULL", Integer.class);
    int id_max = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT MAX(" + column + ") from " + table + " WHERE " + column + " IS NOT NULL", Integer.class);
    int id_half = 0;

    try {
        id_half = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT MAX(" + column + ") from " + table + " WHERE " + column + " IS NOT NULL " + " and " + column + " < " + Math.ceil((id_max - id_min) / 2.0), Integer.class); 
        // The above line is number 36
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // THIS SHOULD NOT HAPPEN!
        log.error("Null Pointer! " + e.getMessage());
        id_half = (id_max - id_min) / 2;
    }

    // ...
}
```

As you see, all the parameters are used before and the only thing that differs in this is the additional condition at the end. Furthermore, this works in a lot of scenarios. Only in one (which is similar to the rest) it causes the null pointer.

Unfortunately, the stack trace does not really help on the matter (try/catch block removed):

```
    2016-05-06 13:51:14,352 [adnb0007] [main] ERROR o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step prepareDeviceDimensionWrapper in job Load_Devices_Cube
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.aspera.dev.sim.loader.util.partitioning.approximations.ApproximationBuilder.buildQuadraticApproximation(ApproximationBuilder.java:36)
    at com.aspera.dev.sim.loader.util.ColumnRangePartitioner.partition(ColumnRangePartitioner.java:85)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.SimpleStepExecutionSplitter.getContexts(SimpleStepExecutionSplitter.java:214)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.SimpleStepExecutionSplitter.split(SimpleStepExecutionSplitter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.AbstractPartitionHandler.handle(AbstractPartitionHandler.java:59)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.PartitionStep.doExecute(PartitionStep.java:106)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(JobLauncherTestUtils.java:152)
    at com.aspera.dev.sim.loader.AbstractIntegrationTest.launchJobTest(AbstractIntegrationTest.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

I am using spring boot version 1.3.3.Release, spring data Gosling-SR1, spring data commons 1.11.2 and spring batch via spring-boot-starter-batch.

Comment: Check that `jdbcTemplate` is not null .

Comment: I think it's a big mistake to concatenate a SQL query instead of using PreparedStatement.  That kind of mistaken thinking is likely to lead to all kinds of other problems.

Comment: @Berger: It can not be null because the two lines above (which also use the same jdbcTemplate) work just fine. I also debugged it (because something strange may happen between the lines) and jdbcTemplate is not null at this point.

Comment: @duffymo thanks for the tip of using prepared statements. However, they still need to be concatenanted because column and table will differ and they can not be replaced by a variable in a prepared statement as far as I know. The values in the where criteria can be though. I will try it.

Comment: ` int id_min ? int id_max ? ` please provide us with this numbers

Comment: No, that's your mistake.  You cannot bind table and column names.  The mistake is imagining that you're saving something by generalizing these max and min queries.  Better to type them out as static strings and use PreparedStatements, even if it's a dozen different columns and tables.  I'd wonder why you think you need that many.

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry as you can see, they come from two other SQL statements two lines further up.

Comment: @Matthiasvianden i'm about values

Comment: @duffymo table and column are configured in the application.yml and are used in numerous places with different SQL statements. It would be (stupid) effort to just have all these different SQL statements duplicated everywhere just differing by the table name and the column. This could be the cause of numerous error all over the application.

Comment: Not stupid.  You are asking for a SQL injection problem this way.  This is an example of a false economy.  Keystrokes are cheap.  Type them and sleep at night, or re-examine how you've decided to solve this problem.

Comment: @duffymo if I add all the SQL statements to the application.yml this has the same (if not even more) potential for injecting problematic SQL. If we would do it, however, we would drastically increase the risk for errors because we have a lot of code duplication all over the place (e.g. if a table or column changes this needs to be replaced in all SQL statements or if something needs to be changed in one statement then this needs to be changes everywhere).

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry the values in the error case are: id_min = 8781 and id_max = 10645

Comment: No, I don't think you understand what SQL injection is.  Sounds like a bad design.  I'd rethink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some scenarios your query returns null because your query filter wont match any records in the database. This will return a null reference which is then assigned to a primitive value id_half.

Java will try to unbox a null giving a NullPointerExcpeption.

Either handle the absence of matching records in your query (might be DB dependent) like so

```
id_half = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT COALESCE(MAX(" + column + ") , 0) from " + table + " WHERE " + column + " IS NOT NULL " + " and " + column + " < " + Math.ceil((id_max - id_min) / 2.0), Integer.class);
```

Or handle the null in your Java code

```
public static DistributionApproximation buildQuadraticApproximation(JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate, String table, String column) {
    int id_min = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT MIN(" + column + ") from " + table + " WHERE " + column + " IS NOT NULL", Integer.class);
    int id_max = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT MAX(" + column + ") from " + table + " WHERE " + column + " IS NOT NULL", Integer.class);
    Integer id_half = 0;

    try {
        id_half = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT MAX(" + column + ") from " + table + " WHERE " + column + " IS NOT NULL " + " and " + column + " < " + Math.ceil((id_max - id_min) / 2.0), Integer.class); 
        if(id_half == null){
           id_half = (id_max - id_min) / 2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much. I also found another error. If I like to get the "middle id" the expression Math.ceil((id_max - id_min) / 2.0) on its own is wrong (this is just the distance between min and max). To get the middle I need to add this on top of min: min + Math.ceil((id_max - id_min) / 2.0), This will also ensure that the SQL will find a record but I will add your suggestion as well.